# SSH Tunnel option of PgAdmin4 not working

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, ssh

I am using PgAdmin4 3.3, and I am trying to setup a server connection to a database through an SSH tunnel.

My database runs on port `30000` on the host. Setting it to `5432` is unfortunately not possible.

When I tunnel that port manually in the terminal it works perfectly: `ssh -L 30000:127.0.0.1:30000 user@host`

My server configuration is then to connect to `localhost` on port `30000`.

If I now disconnect the ssh session and try to configure it directly in the pgAdmin UI, it wont work.

[image: pgAdmin4 SSH Tunnel Tab]

After I save the config and try to connect to the database it takes about a minute and then I get a connection lost message.

Thanks in advance!